# Specified cast not valid Dataset

Tags: c#, sql

I have a stored procedure that returns 4000 records

```
SELECT 
cast(Number as bigint) as Number
FROM  TableTest
```

This query runs fine and returns the results

However when i do this in the C#

```
    public static MDTSearchResult MDTSearchResultReader(SqlDataReader rdr)
    {
        MDTSearchResult r = new MDTSearchResult();
        {
            r.person = new person()
            {
                Number = (long)rdr["Number"]
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
```

> I get an error saying specified cast not valid, on this

I have checked the length of all records in the returned data set (Column Number) they are all a length of 10 and are all bigints.

Is there any other reason for this.

Also I have debugged in VS and noticed it gets through the first 500 records ( i did then stop as it was too time consuming.)

Thanks

Comment: In your query you're aliasing the column name as `Test`, but in your code you're referencing it as `Number`.

Comment: Put a Try/Catch block around your cast to Long. Then put a breakpoint in the "catch" part, so you'll stop at the right record with the invalid value?

Comment: if you did a copy paste of your actual code, you are missing a closing curly braces after Number =  line.

Comment: Sorry i had to change the column names, they do match in the application and SPROC

Comment: Again sorry i had to strip a lot out and forgot to add the curly brace back in on Stack Overflow

Comment: @S.Gray post the *actual* error text and the table schema. You may be reading from the wrong field. Or the error may come from SQL Server saying that `Number` can't be cast, perhaps because it's a string field containing data that can't be parsed as numbers

Comment: rdr.GetInt64(0) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint64?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @S.Gray `specified cast not valid` is a SQL Server error indeed. It means that the contents of `Number` are wrong. What is that field's type and what are the contents that cause the problem? If the field has a text type (eg varchar) *why*? That can only cause errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have checked the results of the SQL procedure and all seem to be 10 digit numbers not starting with 0 and if i Cast it within SQL the query runs fine.

Comment: Obviously not - `specified cast not valid` is a SQL Server error. If you use a text type for that field, you have a bug, period. What's the field's type? Why do you have to `cast` it to a `bigint` to begin with? If it's a `bigint` just return it as-is

Comment: In order to figure out whether all are bigints (number data type) or possible values of strings, instead of using direct cast ((long)rdr["Number"]), I would use, Convert.ToInt64(rdr["Number"]) and if there are any 0's in the Number, then that/those record/s could be cross-verified with database values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
public static MDTSearchResult MDTSearchResultReader(SqlDataReader rdr)
{
    MDTSearchResult r = new MDTSearchResult();

    do
    {
        // Not sure your MDTSearchResult definition, you are overwriting person object.
        r.person = new person();        
        r.person.Number = !rdr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Number")) ? Convert.ToInt64(rdr["Number"]) : 0L;
    }while (rdr.NextResult())
    return r;
}
```